# Is it possible to make GridLayout's components not equal in size?

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

`GirdLayout` makes a bunch of components equal in size. That means that the biggest sized component will define the size for all components. Is it possible to make each component's size based on their inner-components instead?

**EDIT:** If it's not possible, how could I get the same effect as a `GridLayout` but with each component's size based on their inner-components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, all cells are equal by design.

Answer (score 5):

No, you'll have to use a different layout manager for that. [`GroupLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/group.html) would be an option.

Comment: @Gnarly: read the section about Component Size and Resizability in the document I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible, but you can use nested components in each cell.  For example, if you don't want a `JButton` to expand to the size of a cell, add it to a `Jpanel`, then add the `JPanel` to the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) is what you need.

Comment: I want the size of each component to be based on it's inner-components. You can't do that with a `GridBagLayout` can you?

Comment: Indeed, you can't. Got u wrong it seems. Maybe a screenshot could help to see what u really try to achieve, but using a groupLayout can perfectly do what u want I guess, nevertheless its not that easy to arrange components in a GroupLayout. With GridBagLayout the design of a component only effects the column and the row, where the component is placed.

But it seems that u dont need something like a grid at all.